R: Spatial relationships between cells of two layers - does the top layer influences the bottom layer?

data <- data.frame(
  Layer = c(rep("TopLayer", 9), rep("BottomLayer", 9)),
  CellNumber = rep(1:9, 2),
  Rows = rep(1:3, each = 3, times = 2),
  Columns = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
              "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  Organism_A = c(2384106527, 1536784094, 1539751217, 1523052513, 
                 1590814987, 1352107649, 1489242422, 1324947256, 
                 1436861411, 28989707.78, 13804448.59, 9445083.257, 
                 10938353.51, 6964463.102, 
                3054182.127, 25332055.04, 6898327.535, 6106191.811),  
  Organism_B = c(2200824832, 689252420.8, 773417652.8, 781621554.2, 
                 900596793.4, 799927709.2, 877576655.6, 882006114.1, 
                 1185177471, 12995607.78, 3990189.403, 3478803.283, 
                 4269672.447, 4336314.549, 1772615.585, 9455652.995, 
                 2166266.218, 3354112.17),  
  Organism_C = c(565141031.9, 407109923.1, 399919019.7, 515591332, 
                 350369021.1, 
                124343494, 236922640.3, 315508071.3, 388405241.6,
                9021589.754, 1282827.48, 289038.1483, 1856107.588, 
                669560.0038, 
                402480.99, 16047493.08, 4076703.421, 2540274.561),   
  Organism_D = c(13886816.39, 5917155.69, 9076079.724, 6364479.436,  
                 6603299.193, 
                2377757.035, 3409059.65, 5316280.163, 7019860.52,
                589742.1374, 50374.84351, 24320.78487, 27717.46694, 
                33827.55107, 
                17236.38709, 2966871.601, 3383635.365, 243522.6605),  
  Organism_E = c(81810916.23, 23506996.31, 33640850.07, 60426641.66, 
                 39478621.87, 
                18547510.22, 28971068.71, 30003359.9, 29142667.22,
                13305779.94, 5571703.603, 2251696.156, 6018467.227, 
                1475516.435, 
                267636.2172, 20126618.14, 28724649.18, 7349550.19)) 

I have two layers on top of each other with 9 cells (Row 1:3 and Column A:C). Inside each cell there are values from 5 different organisms. I want to find out if there are connections between the cells on top of each other. In other words, are there spatial patterns? Does the Top Layer influences the Bottom layer?
Can can I accomplish this? Is this crosscorrelation? Is there a way to spatialy show similarities?
I can use R or Python.
